# Where do I get the app roles details from Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm calling this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='yadayada')/appRoleAssignedTo
```

And I get this:

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('yadayada')/appRoleAssignedTo",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "oaFkuO69-EamCp_0kyQ9kWaoyPYCtwhOmT4DvtthXrg",
        "appRoleId": "363ace06-7e6c-4608-b9fa-2897ab889228",
        "principalDisplayName": "Muhammad Farid Ahamat"
    },
    {
        "id": "CH4rVVG3PUSClKh-Mkl9qfyj147wXfJDjgRPnViC2ks",
        "appRoleId": "8effb34c-d7e5-43c5-a86d-56e38f9e313e",
        "principalDisplayName": "Normal User"
    }
]
```

How do I get the information about the appRoleId? Basically, I want to get this:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the service principal or application object?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you want to get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='yadayada')/appRoles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created  **App Roles**  in Azure AD Application:

[image]

To fetch the App Roles assigned to the Application, make use of  **Service Principal ObjectID**:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/vgRr4xi.png)]

And make use of the below Graph API query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/SPObjId/appRoles
```

[image]

**Output:**

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('xxx')/appRoles",
"value": [
{
"allowedMemberTypes": [
"User"
],
"description": "Admin can do all admin stuff",
"displayName": "Admin",
"id": "xxx",
"isEnabled": true,
"origin": "Application",
"value": "Admin.All"
},
{
"allowedMemberTypes": [
"User"
],
"description": "Normal user get to do all",
"displayName": "Normal",
"id": "xxx",
"isEnabled": true,
"origin": "Application",
"value": "Normal.All"
}
]
}
```